# How to round second

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `datetime` column in the following format.

How to round to seconds, it looks like `miliseconds` after second (after the point):

```
Event End DateTime
2016-09-09 10:49:21.9613415
2016-09-09 10:49:21.9783415
```

I need:

```
Event Start DateTime
2016-09-09 10:49:22
2016-09-09 10:49:22
```

Comment: Use `datetime2(0)` instead of `datetime`, or cast to the same type

Answer (score 3):

Try

`SELECT CAST(datecolumn AS datetime2(0))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `datetime2(0)` instead of `datetime`. This will allow you to store values without second fractions.

[datetime2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) has a higher range than `datetime` and  allows you to specify the fractional second precision you want. While `datetime` only allows dates from 1753-01-01, `datetime2` works with dates from 0001-01-01 to 9999-12-31

If you have to use `datetime` anyway, you can cast to `datetime2(0)`, eg:

```
SELECT cast(GETDATE() as datetime2(0))
```

This will return the datetime value without fractionals as a `DATETIME2` value. 
All T-SQL functions work with `datetime2` and the values translate directly to `System.DateTime`. If you *have* to use this as a `datetime` though, you can cast it back:

```
select cast(cast(getdate() as datetime2(0)) as datetime)
```